# Single double qoute backtick escape special character rich string

Tags: go

I need to assign an unwieldy special character rich string to a variable in Go.  The string contains single, double quotes as well as backticks.

example:

```
licKey := `sQO*=+=ZG7#UXz!I:C&?sNUfg`j.*C!29x,HP|@=wJ;],{N;?rmc}b4~$ma,>p._9(&Xj4PQ3RhzF6#B;}cf0jFx`=qZYl|IB9/_d85P?PeD>,te9~sfPlCeNM$X;VZ/aWR-WEZ//oP&yO^SsGEI:5CyeZsWK{uREUI6tD@TC&?8fHQ^a0wLhmxBkPBZ]U/&8?T$VUAGx#:.XSu%azB{/H,ejiGss.T)D5U]O6JmEIEdEC+q5-C*e&T~]Q&YaYl0<B;tSx0i'_c+ZC2'W]c&b0Aud&b_fnv_<#3x2C4USSXkOL&}MNC=z-6#`Oy)D!fc+=bQ,vZF`
```

I've wrapped the string itself in backticks (`), but as you can see, there are back ticks throughout the string itself.

One method that comes to mind is externalizing the string into a text file and reading it from there and assigning the variable to contents:

```
raw, err := ioutil.ReadFile(<filePath>)
if err != nil {
    return
}
licKey := string(raw)
```

I just wanted to check if there is maybe some other approach built into the standard libraries that could help that anyone knows of? Maybe escaping?

Comment: `\\`` did you try backslashes to escape the ticks in the string?

Comment: that doesn't work

Comment: the backtick makes everything literal so no character substitutions.  However, if I use double quotes and escape the double qoutes using \ preceeding the ", then it does work.    cool

Comment: You could say base64 or hex-encode it. But it really is easier to use double quotes and escape them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the string in double-quotes and use a backslash to escape any double-quotes or backslashes within the string.

```golang
    licKey := "sQO*=+=ZG7#UXz!I:C&?sNUfg\`j.*C!29x,HP|@=wJ;],{N;?rmc}b4~$ma,>p._9(&Xj4PQ3RhzF6#B;}cf0jFx`=qZYl|IB9/_d85P?PeD>,te9~sfPlCeNM$X;VZ/aWR-WEZ//oP&yO^SsGEI:5CyeZsWK{uREUI6tD@TC&?8fHQ^a0wLhmxBkPBZ]U/&8?T$VUAGx#:.XSu%azB{/H,ejiGss.T)D5U]O6JmEIEdEC+q5-C*e&T~]Q&YaYl0<B;tSx0i'_c+ZC2'W]c&b0Aud&b_fnv_<#3x2C4USSXkOL&}MNC=z-6#`Oy)D!fc+=bQ,vZF"
```

If you are looking to convert control characters and non-printable characters, take a look at [strconv.Quote](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Quote)